# PHP driver for Cassandra from installation error mac

Tags: php, cassandra

I was trying to install the php driver on Mac OSX 10.9 Mavericks and then it gave me this error:

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See `config.log' for more details
```

What could be the issue with this?

Place where I got driver: https://github.com/datastax/php-driver

Comment: @pavlovich I have administrative permissions so I dont think that is the problem.

Comment: I have figured out this problem